# Holding agents before a select output element to avoid default port

Tags: anylogic

I've been trying to model a scenario but still cannot find the best way to do it. The scenario is as follows:

*Agents arrive at a point where they need to choose one of three paths. Each path is a delay with capacity 1. If the first path already has an agent in it (in the delay block), then the 1st condition is not met and the agent tries the second port. In the second port, if the delay block is available it can proceed, otherwise it checks the third. If all are busy, then the agent should wait in a queue before the select output.*

To model this process, I used the following sequence:

Queue > Hold > Select Output 5 > 1 Delay element of capacity 1 after each of the three first output ports of the select output

The condition for the select output is for example "Delay1.size() == 0" then for the second port "Delay2.size() == 0", etc.

Then, I created a function that checks if all delay.size() == 1, then the hold element is set to blocked to avoid having agents going through the select output's default port. The function is tested at every "On Enter" and "On Exit" fields of all the blocks.

Despite the above, agents are still going through the default port which means that the hold element is not working properly.

Is there a more efficient way to model the described scenario? Thank you!

Comment: why doesn't a queue followed by a delay with capacity 3 work for you instead?

Comment: I simplified the model a bit. Each delay has some additional characteristics. For example, each delay will have some down time specific to itself. So they need to be separate lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are not actually blocking your Hold element at all, hence agents will walk through anytime :-)

There are many ways for such a situation.

You could replace the Delay with a Wait element instead. Whenever an agent leaves one of your Delay blocks, you unblock the Hold.

Whenever an agent passes the Hold, you block it, but only if all 3 pathes are currently busy.

Should do the trick